# Ubuntu KVM failed to set up

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, python, linux-kvm

I'm trying to set up a VM with KVM on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine (64 bit). I followed the installation instructions to the letter at http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts and the command `virsh -c qemu:///system` appears to be working fine (it brings me to an interface where I can enter commands to virsh)

However, whenever I try to create a VM I always get this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/vmbuilder", line 24, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/contrib/cli.py", line 142, in main
    hypervisor, distro = self.handle_args(optparser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/contrib/cli.py", line 292, in handle_args
    distro = VMBuilder.get_distro(args[1])()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/distro.py", line 75, in __init__
    super(Distro, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/distro.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.plugins = [plugin_class(self) for plugin_class in self.plugin_classes]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/plugins/__init__.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.register_options()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/plugins/network/__init__.py", line 70, in register_options
    domainname = '.'.join(socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[0].split('.')[1:]) or "defaultdomain"
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

These are the commands that I have tried and all of them result in the same error

`vmbuilder kvm ubuntu -c vm2.cfg`
`ubuntu-vm-builder kvm hardy \
        --domain testvm \
        --dest testvm \
        --arch i386 \
        --hostname testvm \
        --mem 256 \
        --user testvm \
        --pass testpass \
        --addpkg avahi-daemon \
        --libvirt qemu:///system ;`

Any help is truly appreciated! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Still a problem, I think I got the error message to be shorter

Answer (score 0):

Please check by hostname -f.

If you get following result,

$ hostname -f

> (result) hostname: Name or service not known

check your hostname by follwoing command, and add  to /etc/hosts.

$ hostname

> (result) YOUR HOSTNAME